# Cant translate custom text (added in funcitions.php) to another language Polylang

Tags: wordpress, translate, polylang

I added custom tab to "My account" and custom text, now i wanna to translate it on another language with Polylang, but i don't understand how to do it, i am not a programmer

Don't try nothing, because i don't know what to do